# Clone Vector in rust except at one index

Tags: comparative-review, rust, vectors

Let's consider you want to clone all items of a vector `orig` except the item of index `i` should be taken from alternative value `alt`.

Lets say the items are of the type

```rust
struct Bla{
  // Some fields
}
```

### Using for loop

On simple solution would be:

```rust
fn clone(orig: &Vec<Bla>, i: usize, alt: Bla) -> Vec<Bla> {
  let cloned = Vec::new();
  for (j, item) in orig.iter().enumerate() {
    let new_item = if i != j {item.clone()} else {alt};
    cloned.push(new_item);
  }  

  cloned
}
```

> Note: Does not compile, because the compiler does not know that `i==j` is only valid once.

### Using functional style

The functional alternative would be the follow:

```rust
fn clone(orig: &Vec<Bla>, i: usize, alt: Bla) -> Vec<Bla> {
  orig.iter().enumerate()
    .map(|(j, item)| if i != j {item.clone()} else {alt})
    .collect::<Vec<Bla>>()
}
```

The last one looks nice, but does not compile :( because the rust compiler does not know that alt gets moved (or consumed) only once (`i==j`).

### Using mem replace

In order to fix the version above one can use a default value for the index which should be replaced.

```rust
fn clone(orig: &Vec<Bla>, i: usize, alt: Bla) -> Vec<Bla> {
  let mut result = orig.iter().enumerate()
    .map(|(j, item)| if i != j {item.clone()} else {Bla::default()})
    .collect::<Vec<Bla>>();

  mem::replace(&mut result[i], alt);
  result
}
```

What is the most concise and fastest implementation to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion none of your solution is idiomatic and all use an useless comparaison.

Using for loop:

- Doesn't pre-allocate the vector
- Use a comparaison that could be avoid

Using functional style:

- Use a comparaison that could be avoid

Using mem replace:

- Use a comparaison that could be avoid
- Is unnecessary complex to just copy a vector

Also, you should avoid take a `&Vec<T>` as parameter, it's much better to take a `&[T]`. See: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/7076153)

I would use one of the following version:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Pokemon {
}

fn a(pokemons: &[Pokemon], i: usize, pokemon: Pokemon) -> Vec<Pokemon> {
    let mut digimons = Vec::with_capacity(pokemons.len());

    digimons.extend_from_slice(&pokemons[0..i]);
    digimons.push(pokemon);
    digimons.extend_from_slice(&pokemons[i + 1..]);

    digimons
}

fn b(pokemons: &[Pokemon], i: usize, pokemon: Pokemon) -> Vec<Pokemon> {
    let mut digimons = pokemons.to_vec();
    digimons[i] = pokemon;

    digimons
}

fn c(pokemons: &[Pokemon], i: usize, pokemon: Pokemon) -> Vec<Pokemon> {
    pokemons[0..i]
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .chain(std::iter::once(pokemon))
        .chain(pokemons[i + 1..].iter().cloned())
        .collect()
}
```

I don't really know witch version is better, `a()` and `c()` **should** be the same but sometime `chain()` is not optimized away. And `b()` is probably the most straightforward solution. I think I would choice `a()` in a production code.

However, looking at the [assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/uLTZwW), we can see that `a()` and `c()` doesn't produce the same, and that `b()` is the simplest.

Comment: But solution `a()` and `c()` avoid copying/cloning `i`th element unnecessary from the incomming slice.

Comment: @Matthias depend on the cost of clone, `b()` "could" be faster. If you really want to be sure, you must do some bench-marking.